# webcam.js not working in Chrome: Webcam is not loaded yet?

Tags: jquery, webcam.js, jquery-webcam-plugin

I am using webcam.js for my asp.net website,after some chrome update the plugin not working.The web camera plugin works on `localhost or https protocol`.But my problem is i published site in LAN network so there is no https protocol,the site access by server IP Address.I also tried chrome unsafely command.

```
--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="http://192.168.1.108/mysite/page" --user-data-dir=c:\chrome-dev-profile http://192.168.1.108/mysite/page
```

Now just white screen shown .

please give some ideas

Comment: Show your javascript code that calls webcam.js.